# How can I regroup several meshes under the same armature?

Tags: mesh, armature

It's probably a basic question, but I'm new to Blender and can't figure it out. Here is the thing:

I've bought modular meshes for a character (head, upper body, hands, etc) on a marketplace and I'm trying to make some modifications in Blender. When I import one of these mesh it imports its skeleton with it, so the hierarchy looks bit messy when I import them all (see picture below). As all these meshes share the exact same skeleton, I'd like to regroup them under the same armature but can't find a way to do it.

Like having only one "root" armature and all the meshes attached to it. Is this possible? And if yes how can I do it? All the tutorials I followed so far didn't help me.

[image]

Comment: If the meshes are parented to the armature and they are on the same folder in the outline they will all appear under it.
 What you have there though, looks like a different armature parented to each part with another duplicated part parented to said armature. All those 'root' objects are different armatures since they have different names. If you provide the file it will be easier to tell but this does not look like you are working with a single armature